# Emails with attachments are getting queued by Gmail app

Tags: gmail, attachments

I am facing this issue with the Gmail app, where the emails without attachments are going through, but the one where I attach something like a pic stored on the mobile, the email gets stuck in the Outbox.
But I can send emails with attachments through the web browser.

**Things I've tried:**

- Uninstalled and installed the Gmail app again
- Updated the apps
- Clear cache + clear data + restart phone

None of them works.

The Permissions page shows Files and Media under the Allowed section, so the permissions should be fine.

Not sure what else I could try.